# Pass dynamic variable from javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php

I have this hidden div

```
<div class="amount" style="display:none;">$30.00</div>
```

I'm getting this div value with Javascript:

```
var price;
window.onload = function(){  
   //Get the value from the amount div     
   price = document.getElementsByClassName('amount')[0].innerHTML; 

   //Set the hidden_price input value (on the form below) to the price
   document.getElementById("hidden_price").value = price; 
};
```

Now I have a form with an hidden input

```
<form action="phpfile.php" method="post">    
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" id="hidden_price">    
    <input type="submit" />            
</form>
```

And when I'm clicking on the submit I have the variable in php

```
 $hidden_price = $_POST['hidden_price'];
```

**Can I have it without submit the form?**

Comment: Actually, to send any data to server side you have to perform `form` submitting or  make `ajax` request.

Comment: Ajax req on page load.

Comment: Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

An equivalent form submit without submitting the form could be:

```
$.post('phpfile.php', $("form").serialize(), .done(function( data ) {
   alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
```